# PHP Round decimals always up to the nearest highest decimal

Tags: php, rounding

I would like to create a rounding methode to round decimals always up to the closest highest decimal value.

for example: `51.13 => 51.20 or 22.33 => 23.40` but lets say `30.10 stays 30.10`

Is this even possible?
Sorry if my explonation is bad but my math english is not the best.

Comment: Anything below or equal to `10` should be rounded, is it? If so, why?

Comment: Looks like you want to multiple by 10, round up, then divide by ten

Comment: @nice_dev yes, because it was request :) our partners requested it, when they enter their cost (purchase) price they wanted to round it up before they apply taxes and their margin.

Comment: @aynber thanks for the tip. I did this `number_format(ceil($number*10)/10, 2, '.', ',')` based on your comment and it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe custom function for rounding ?

something like this

```
    $inputNumber=51.13;
    
        function round2deci($number){
        $explode = explode(".", $number);
        /// 51.13 == 51.ab
        $a = substr($explode[1], 0, 1);
        $b =  substr($explode[1], 1, 2);
        // fix for 51.91
        if($a == 9){
        $explode[0]++;
        $a = 0;
        $b = 0;
        
    }
        if($b > 0){
            $a++;
        }
        echo $explode[0].".".$a."0";
        }
        
        round2deci($inputNumber);
```

and result is :

```
51.20
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php#108370) answer on the php.net website under the `ceil` docs that does exactly what you want.

I've added an improved version below which returns a pure float where you'd be able to apply `number_format` to preserve the trailing zeros of the decimals:

```php
function ceil_dec(float $number, int $precision = 2, string $separator = '.') : float
{
    $numberpart    = explode($separator, (string)$number);
    $numberpart[1] = substr_replace($numberpart[1], $separator, $precision, 0);
    if ($numberpart[0] >= 0) {
        $numberpart[1] = ceil($numberpart[1]);
    } else {
        $numberpart[1] = floor($numberpart[1]);
    }

    $ceil_number = [$numberpart[0], $numberpart[1]];

    return (float)implode($separator, $ceil_number);
}

var_dump(
    ceil_dec(10.23,1)
);
```

The above code is good for PHP 7.0 and above, and with `declare(strict_types = 1)` enabled.